# how to receive message from BackgroundJS and change state in ReactJS and Chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I wish to receive a message from backgroundJS of my chrome extension and change state of React DOM.

```
...
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      message: ''
    };
  }
 func() {
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"hello"})
 }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.message}</div>
    )
  }
}
background.js
...
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.type == 'hello')
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'How are you'});
})
```

How can I get the message from backgroundJS and change this.state.**message** to "How are you" received?

Comment: Add chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener in the constructor and either save `this` in some variable which you can use in the onMessage callback or simply use the arrow function syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works exactly the same way going the other direction. You're already halfway there. I would make the messaging a bit more robust so that you can specify a target, type, and content of the messages that you're sending, as well as the extension ID so that other extensions can't listen in (not that they necessarily would, but it's good practice.)

```
...
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      message: ''
    };
    this.handleMessage.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Add listener when component mounts
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(this.handleMessage);
  }
  handleMessage(msg) {
   // Handle received messages
   if (msg.target === 'app') {
    if (msg.type === 'setMessage') {
     this.setState({message: msg.body});
    }
   }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
   // Remove listener when this component unmounts
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(this.handleMessage);
  }
  func() {
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, {target: 'background', type: 'message', body: 'hello'})
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.message}</div>
    )
  }
}

// background.js
...
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.target === 'background') {
  if (request.type === 'message') {
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, {target: 'app', type: 'setMessage', body: 'How are you'});
  }
 }
})
```

Edit: Apparently you can omit the `chrome.runtime.id` if you want because if absent the extension will default to sending to itself.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being very late to the party, just want to add to jered's answer: instead of adding `this.handleMessage.bind(this);` inside constructor(), add this in here

```
componentDidMount() {
// Add listener when component mounts
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(this.handleMessage.bind(this));
}
```

works for me